# Regex for every dot number 3 in a string

Tags: php, regex

The string I talk about is something like the following:

```
xxxxx.xxxxxx.xxx.yyyyyyy.yyyyyy.yyyyyyyy.zzzz
```

Where x,y and z are anything other than "." (dot) i.e alphanumeric, special characters, spaces, new line, etc.

I tried:

```
(\w|\d|\s){1,}.\.{3,}
```

Comment: Your regexp is looking for at least 3 dots in a row. Why do you have `{3,}` there?

Comment: What part of the string are you actually trying to match? What do you mean by _dot number 3_?

Comment: I mean every third dot in a string i.e suppose we have a string contains 10 dots so I want to match dot number: 3, 6 and 9.

Comment: Every third dot match position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
(?:[^.]+\.){3}
```

This applies the `{3}` quantifier to the entire group, not just the `.` at the end of each group. Since you want match exactly 3 groups, I use `{3}`; `{3,}` means 3 or more groups.

And it uses the simpler `[^.]` to match everything except `.` (it's not necessary to escape dot inside brackets, since it doesn't have any special meaning there).

To use this in `preg_replace` to replace each third dot, you need to match everything *before* that dot in a capture group. Then you can use `$1` to copy that to the replacement string.

```
preg_replace('/((?:[^.]+\.){2}[^.]+)\./', '$1<br/>', $string);
```

Comment: This very good solution and it may be handled by further functions. However, does it possible to match the thirds dots itself?

Comment: I've added a capture group around the dot. I'm not sure why you need to match the dots themselves, though? The value of it will always just be a dot.

Comment: I have long article text without any newlines so I'd like to replace every third dot with `<br />` using `preg_replace()`

Comment: Then you actually want to match the text _before_ the dots, so you can keep it in the replacement

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked perfectly. This is a demo: http://codepad.org/RHdIeo3H

Answer (score 1):

Use `^` in front of a character to match everything but this character

```
 ([^\.]+\.){3,}
```